# Spring Security OAuth 2 with Grails 3.0 and Spring Security Core Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security-oauth2, grails-3.0

I try to use Spring Security OAuth 2 in my project

My project is a Grails 3.0.9 application with Spring Security Core Plugin

I just want authorize a client (like a mobile) to connect with a user login/password

For OAuth 2, this is my configuration
      @Configuration
        public class Oauth2Config {

```
        @Configuration
        @EnableAuthorizationServer
        protected static class AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
            @Autowired
            private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
            @Override
            public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
                endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            }
            @Override
            public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
                // @formatter:off
                clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("client-with-registered-redirect")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                        .scopes("read", "trust")
                        .redirectUris("http://localhost:8080")
                        .secret("secret")
                    .and()
                    .withClient("client-with-secret")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                        .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                        .secret("secret");
                // @formatter:on
            }
        }

        @Configuration
        @EnableResourceServer
        protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
            @Override
            public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                // !! Not enter inside !!
                // @formatter:off
                http
                    .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api").and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
                // @formatter:on
            }
            @Override
            public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
                resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
            }
        }

    }
```

When I call this URL (POST)

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?
client_id=client-with-secret&
redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&
scope=read&
secret=secret&
grant_type=password&
login=toto&
password=toto
```

I have this response

```
{
    error: "unauthorized"
    error_description: "There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter."
}
```

I notice that :

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/1b2ae987e9486a875b40424f18bb785baf0b898c/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/token", method=RequestMethod.POST)
            public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> postAccessToken(Principal principal, @RequestParam
            Map<String, String> parameters) throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {

                if (!(principal instanceof Authentication)) {
                    throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                            "There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter.");
                }
}
```

I need to be authenticated before ?!

I notice too :
The debuger not enter inside this method : 
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception

And also : OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter is never call

Need help 
Thanks